# Display complex mathematical equations in iOS 5.0 devices

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on an app for iPhone and iPod Touch that has to show complex mathematical equations like algebraic, integration, summation formulas along with some text.

For that I have used Quartz2D and below is what I have created. Can anyone please verify if this is the correct procedure to draw an equation?

I have to show lots of text with inline equations (and that too dynamic) - I am sure using this procedure will be a task to make that thing dynamic.

P.S. - I just need verification of my below procedure or if there is a more feasible solution - please guide me to that.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Left hand side Starts --
float xaxis = 3.0f;

// Before bracket
NSString *textString = @"L";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

// Opening bracket
xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 30.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]];

textString = @"N";
xaxis += 12.0f;
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

// Numerator part
unichar oneChar[] = {0x2206};
xaxis += 31.0f;
textString = getTextString(oneChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

unichar twoChar[] = {0x03C9};
xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = getTextString(twoChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 48.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Line
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, 45, 65);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(myContext, 110, 65);
CGContextStrokePath(myContext);

// Denominator part
xaxis -= 40.0f;
unichar threeChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(threeChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 74.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
unichar fourChar[] = {0x0028};
textString = getTextString(fourChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar fiveChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(fiveChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Closing bracket
xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 30.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]];

// Equal to sign
xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar sixChar[] = {0x003D};
textString = getTextString(sixChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Right hand side Starts --

// Numerator part
xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"sin";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 42.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 20.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Inner opening bracket
xaxis += 10.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"N";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
unichar sevenChar[] = {0x03C0};
textString = getTextString(sevenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 40.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
unichar eightChar[] = {0x2206};
textString = getTextString(eightChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 36.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:21]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar nineChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(nineChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 47.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"/";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar tenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(tenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 48.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar elevenChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(elevenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Inner closing bracket
xaxis += 6.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

// Line    
CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, 138, 65);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(myContext, 318, 65);
CGContextStrokePath(myContext);

// Denominator part
xaxis -= 175.0f;    
textString = @"N";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 65.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 63.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"sin";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 68.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 20.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 63.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Inner opening bracket
xaxis += 10.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar twelveChar[] = {0x03C0};
textString = getTextString(twelveChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 68.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
unichar thirteenChar[] = {0x2206};
textString = getTextString(thirteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 65.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:21]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar fourteenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(fourteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 67.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 75.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"/";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar fifteenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(fifteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 67.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 75.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar sixteenChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(sixteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Inner closing bracket
xaxis += 6.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

// Extra text for information
xaxis = 6.0f;
textString = @"Above is the example of an equation drawn using";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 120.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
xaxis = 6.0f;
textString = @"Quartz2D";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 140.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];

}

static NSString *getTextString(unichar chars[], int charLength)
{   
NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:chars length: charLength];
return uniString;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the code here: https://github.com/kostub/iosMath That will help you with rendering math equations using CoreText.

Answer (score 2):

These questions may be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340478/rendering-mathematical-formulas-on-an-idevice

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243539/tradeoff-between-latex-mathml-and-xhtmlmathml-in-an-ios-app

As for the rendering, Quartz2D is one approach. Or, my preference, you could go for an HTML/CSS based approach, as mentioned at the above question. The use of [Texify](http://www.texify.com/) looks tempting!

If you take entirely your own approach for the rendering (e.g. using Quartz2D), I imagine a robust solution to maths rendering will involve three distinct parts that need to interact:

1. a representation of the equation
2. a layout engine to decide how to position elements on the page
3. an engine that actually displays the items as decreed by (2) -- be it Quartz2D, HTML/CSS, or something else

Food for thought on representing an equation:

You can represent an expression as a tree structure. Each node is composed of both:

1. some sort of operator (be it binary, such as '+', '=' or '*', or unary, e.g. 'sin', square root, etc.)
2. links to child nodes which are the operands to its operator.

So the nodes form a recursive structure.